# Member function, unable to deduce ‘auto’

Tags: c++, function-pointers, auto

I'm wondering if it's possible in c++ to get pure function pointer from member function of an object.

```
class AS
{
    int x;
public:
    AS(int xx)
    {
        x = xx;
    }

    void ww(void* p)
    {
        std::cerr << "AS::ww " << x << std::endl;
    }
};

void exp()
{
    void* pp = 0;
    AS aa(9);
    ((aa).*(&AS::ww))(pp);//compiles and work fine
    auto ff = ((aa).*(&AS::ww));//not compiling
}
```

I've tried just keeping the calling part:

```
    auto ff = ((aa).*(&AS::ww));
```

but this gives me `error: unable to deduce ‘auto’ from ‘aa.*&AS::ww’`

so why is that? It has no type?

How do you call one who has no type?

Comment: Member functions are weird. The only thing you are allowed to do with `((aa).*(&AS::ww))` is to call the function.

Comment: Well, no so weird. You need to provide all arguments to call a function, and `this` is effectively one of those arguments. You cannot provide just one of the two arguments to a function call, and `((aa).*(&AS::ww))` is missing the `void* p` argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIRC some implementations support to keep such closures in objects, but it isn't standard compliant. [expr.mptr.oper]/6:

> If the result of `.*` or `->*` is a function, then **that result can be used
>   only as the operand for the function call operator `()`.**

However, as of C++11 (which you must be using since you're using `auto`), use `std::bind` or a lambda:

```
auto ff = [&] (void* p) {return aa.ww(p);};
```

Comment: Depending on the use case, `std::mem_fn` might be a good choice.

Comment: @T.C. The asker wants a function object that stores the object argument, doesn't he?

Comment: @Columbo I wanted a pure function pointer `void (*)(void* p)` independent from the class and the object. So a capture lambda doesn't really changes much here, since I still can't pass it around freely. I guess it's just impossible in c++, yet.

Comment: @Vladp Consider that (a) each such function pointer would have to be unique, so that two such function pointers would "know" to use a different object instance, and this would require runtime code generation (not possible on all platforms, such as iOS) and (b) at some point the memory used for generated native code for the function pointer would need to be deallocated -- can you identify when that should be?

Comment: @Vladp: C++11 added an implicit conversion from **noncapturing** lambda's to function pointer. This "noncapturing" restriction wasn't added to be annoying, but because it's necessary on a number of reasonable platforms.

Answer (score 0):

This particular problem is typically caused by interfacing with C callbacks (the `void* argument is a giveaway). The solution is to realize that in these cases, *you* control the void*.

Thus:

```
class AS
{
    int x;
public:
    AS(int xx)
    {
        x = xx;
    }
    void ww()
    {
        std::cerr << "AS::ww " << this << std::endl;
    }
    static void ww(void* p)
    {
        static_cast<AS*>(p)->ww();
    }
};
setupCcallback(&AS::ww, static_cast<void*>(&aa));
```